# Angular 5 Reactive Form Pattern Validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to come up with a validation pattern in Reactive Form (Form Control) using Validators.pattern. The conditions are Alphanumeric, Only underscore_, hyphen- are allowed. Any type of space should not be allowed. Is there any one single pattern that will help me achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Validators.pattern with FormBuilder
We can use `Validators.pattern` for pattern validation while creating form either by `FormBuilder` or by `FormGroup`. Here we will provide code snippet for `FormBuilder`.

```
unamePattern = "^[a-z0-9_-]{8,15}$";
userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
username: ['', Validators.pattern(this.unamePattern)],})
```

But if you dont want to allow "-" just use this

```
unamePattern = "^[a-z0-9_]{8,15}$";
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/)`

Answer (score 3):

It works for me.

1. In .ts file write the following code.

   ```
   pattern="^[ a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$";

   this.projectRoleAssignFrom =  this.formBuilder.group({
      userName : [''],
      userRole : [''],
      project : [''],
      searchInput : ['', Validators.pattern(this.pattern)]
    })
   ```
2. in html file wrire the following code.

   ```
     <div class="form-group">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-select placeholder="Select User" formControlName="userName"
                                (click)="clearSearchField()">
                                <div class="searchbar">
                                    <md-input-container class="full-width-ex" color="accent">
                                        <input mdInput #input type="text" class="searchbar-input"
                                            (input)="filterAssociates($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search User"
                                            formControlName="searchInput">
                                    </md-input-container>
                                    <mat-error class="alert-danger" *ngIf="projectRoleAssignFrom.get('searchInput').hasError('pattern')" >
                                        Invalid User</mat-error>
                                </div>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredAssociatesList" [value]="user.fullName"
                                    (click)="getValues('user', user.id)">
                                    {{ user.fullName }}
                                </mat-option>
                                <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="userName.invalid && userName.touched"></mat-error> -->
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
 pattern1 =  "^[0-9_-]{10,12}$";
 phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern1)]]
```